# React Native fetch returns 404 but postman does 200 ok

Tags: react-native, get, fetch, http-status-code-404, spotify

I am integrating Spotify web api into react native application. I have problem with React Native fetch. When I call the api inside Postman, I get 200 response code but if I run it inside emulator(react native) I get 404 error code. I also wrote the fetch request inside chrome console and it works good but in react native it is not working.

The code that I am running:

```js
let response = await fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/featured-playlists?locale=en_US&country=US`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
           'Authorization': 'Bearer BQDT3_xtYLyIsGaqhoTM42Z-k3ijs-hFbzIG89basd7Me-kL4SUWSLgQrxWN3b13DiqU6THfr4VH4Z7klnc' 
        }
    });
    console.log("response",response.status)
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found any solution?

Comment: No, I left that project away.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code in React Native v. 0.58.6

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let spotifyApiUrl = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/featured-playlists?locale=en_US&country=US";
    let fetchSettings =  {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer BQDT3_xtYLyIsGaqhoTM42Z-k3ijs-hFbzIG89basd7Me-kL4SUWSLgQrxWN3b13DiqU6THfr4VH4Z7klnc' 
        }
    };

    fetch(spotifyApiUrl, fetchSettings)
        .then( (response) => response.json() )
        .then( (responseJson) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

With the following console output:

```
{"error":{"status":401,"message":"The access token expired"}}
```

Have you tried plugging in your actual device to see if it is an emulator issue?
Remember to forward tcp ports on adb before running "react-native run-android" if you use a real device

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
react-native run-android
```

Comment: Did you also try with my code? If it still not work try to call another url and see if you keep getting 404.

Comment: Yes I tried your code but nothing changed. I only have 404 with spotify url, others are working fine.

Comment: So, you tried with my code, using a real device, trying with different urls, and the problem persist only with spotify url. if you are using Android try to clean gradle cache using "gradlew clean" inside android directory and run the app again. What is the response message with the 404? "Resource not found"?